# ReactJs: One Explicit focus() method on input does not allow me to change the color of link using tabindex in the same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some text links on my page and one input element. I want to change the color of my text link from "blue" to "green" when the link is clicked until another link is clicked or input is selected. But the problem is I am already using one explicit focus() method using refs on the input field due to which the color of the link does not retaining. Is there any way in React Js to do that. As i am new to react and already tried for so many days to find the solution.
Below is the code for my text link. Here i am using css class "higlight-text" and tabindex to retain the color using focus method. But its not retaining.

```
<div style={{"border": "1px solid lightgray"}} className="mb-20">
<span className="inline ml-20 mt-10 mb-10 mr-40"><b>Status</b></span>
<span className="excellent_status_15 inline mr-0"></span>
<span className="inline mr-30 pointer highlight-text" tabindex="-1" onClick={()=> this.handleStatusClick("Online")}><h4 className="inline">{numOnline}</h4>Online</span>
 <span className="good_status_15 inline mr-0"></span>
 <span className="inline mr-30 pointer highlight-text" tabindex="-1" onClick={()=> this.handleStatusClick("Offline")}><h4 className="inline">{numOffline}</h4>Offline</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?
https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-architecture-gqr1m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No, I have some text links like:   6 Offline     0 Online     like this. I want that when i click on any of this text link the color of this text "6 Offline" will change to green as previously it was blue. But due to the input element it is not retaining the color. It just shows the color if I hold the mouse button there. These links just filter the table below them so i want till the particular link is clicked it will become green and when the other link is clicked, it will go back to blue and the currently clicked link becomes green. Just to show that which link is currently active.

Comment: I've updated my codesandbox example, can you check and see if that is what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, somewhat similar to that. But one more thing I want to know that you have used text for storing the items like Online, Offline and Away. But in my case, the text is in different span. So, can you please tell me how can I use this code on that.

Comment: Pretty much the same, just move them out of the array, I've updated my example from codesandbox

Comment: Please check the code above and kindly tell me how can I modify my code to add your suggestions. As I find it difficult to understand how can i use two "onClick" methods and set the color of the links